# problema al enviar insert into, el formulario no es enviado

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una bdd llamada 'hospital', con una tabla llamada 'sala_habitación',que a su vez tiene los campos ID_habitación, Número, Planta y Disponibilidad. La idea en el aplicativo es mostrar un formulario que envíe datos a mysql y que a la vez muestre en tiempo real los datos que tiene la tabla, esta segunda parte me funciona, pero al realizar el insert no ocurre nada y ya no sé donde puede estar el error.
El primer archivo es la conexión con la base de datos el segundo el archivo sala_habitación y el último la vista_salahabitacion

```
<?php
class BD{
public static $instancia=null;
public static function crearInstancia(){
    
    if(  !isset(self::$instancia) ){
     $opciones[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
     self::$instancia = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hospital', 'root', '', $opciones);
     echo "conectado...";

    }

    return self::$instancia;
}
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
include_once '../configuracion/bd.php';


$conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();

$ID_habitación=isset($_POST['ID_habitación'])?$_POST['ID_habitación']:'';
$Número=isset($_POST['Número'])?$_POST['Número']:'';
$Planta=isset($_POST['Planta'])?$_POST['Planta']:'';
$Disponibilidad=isset($_POST['Disponibilidad'])?$_POST['Disponibilidad']:'';
$accion=isset($_POST['accion'])?$_POST['accion']:'';


if($accion!=''){
switch($accion){

   case 'agregar':
     $sql="INSERT INTO sala_habitación (ID_habitación, Número, Planta, Disponibilidad) VALUES (:ID_habitación,:Número,:Planta,:Disponibilidad)";
     $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
     $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación',$ID_habitación);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Número',$Número);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Planta',$Planta);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Disponibilidad',$Disponibilidad);
    $consulta->execute();
   break;

   case 'editar':
   $sql="UPDATE sala_habitación SET ID_habitación=:ID_habitación, Número=:Número, Planta=:Planta, Disponibilidad=:Disponibilidad WHERE ID_habitación=:ID_habitación";
   $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
   $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación,$ID_habitación');
   $consulta->execute();
break;

   case 'borrar':
   $sql="DELETE FROM sala_habitación WHERE ID_habitación=$ID_habitación";
   $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
   $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación,$ID_habitación');
   $consulta->execute();
break;
}


}


$consulta=$conexionBD->prepare("SELECT * FROM sala_habitación");
$consulta->execute();
$lista_salahabitacion=$consulta->fetchAll(); 
?>
```

---

```
<?php include('../templates/cabecera.php'); ?>
<?php include('../secciones/sala_habitacion.php'); ?>

<h1 class="display-3"> Habitaciones y Salas</h1>
<br/>

<form>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <br>
    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-5">
<div class="mb-3">

<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">HABITACIÓN</div>
   <div class="card-body">
   <div class="mb-3">
 <label for="" class="form-label">ID_habitación</label>
 <input type="text"
   class="form-control"
   name="ID_habitación"
   id="ID_habitación"
   aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="ID_habitación">
</div>
 
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="" class="form-label">Número</label>
 <input type="text"
   class="form-control"
   name="Número"
   id="Número"
   aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Número">
</div>
 
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="" class="form-label">Planta</label>
 <input type="text"
   class="form-control"
   name="Planta"
   id="Planta"
   aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Planta">
</div>
 
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="" class="form-label">Disponibilidad</label>
 <input type="text"
   class="form-control"
   name="Disponibilidad"
   id="Disponibilidad"
   aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Disponibilidad">
</div>
<br>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
   <button type="submit" name="accion" value="agregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
   <button type="submit" name="accion" value="editar" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
   <button type="submit" name="accion" value="borrar" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>


</div>
 </div>

</form>





<div class="col-7">
<table class="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>NÚMERO</th>
           <th>PLANTA</th>
           <th>DISPONIBILIDAD</th>
          
 
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 
<?php foreach($lista_salahabitacion as $sala){ ?>
   <tr>
           <td> <?php echo $sala['ID_habitación']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $sala['Número']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $sala['Planta']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $sala['Disponibilidad']; ?> </td>
          
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php include('../templates/piepagina.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formulario sí se envía, pero tienes un error en tu código HTML.

Si te fijas, tienes dos etiquetas `<form>` (y otras dos `</form>`) una dentro de la otra. Esto hace que cuando envias el formulario se sigan las indicaciones de la primera etiqueta declarada, que no tiene definida el atributo `method` y, por lo tanto, utiliza el valor por defecto de la misma, que es GET y no POST.

Elimina esas etiquetas `<form>` (la que está bajo el título `h1`) y `</form>` que te sobran y así `<form action="" method="POST">` ya debería enviar los campos del formulario correctamente.